# Jenkins github webook payload

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to get the payload sent by a github webhook to jenkins and also use the branch_specifier in the job?

The only way i could get the payload was using This Build is Parameterized and using a String Parameter in the job configuration (as stated in [this link](http://chloky.com/github-json-payload-in-jenkins/)), but by changing the URL to specify the job (and by using the [Build Token Root Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin?focusedCommentId=82020201&#comment-82020201)) the branch specifier is no longer used so the job is triggered for all jobs.

Is there another way of getting the payload from github so i can use it in my script?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) can do that.

The entire payload can be resolved with a JSONPath like `$`. Or if you want just some value within the JSON, you can point that out and have it assigned to a variable.